# Add item to Value service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have the following:

```
.value('objs', {item1:'some item',item2:'another item'});
```

And I want to add items to this. So I created a controller for that:

```
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, objs){    
    $scope.addToObjs = function(i){
        objs.push(i);           
    }

    $scope.addToObjs({item3:'and another item'});
});
```

Is this not possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call push on an object. Try doing this:

```
$scope.addToObjs = function(i){
    angular.extend(objs, i);           
}
```